# Unexpected token error using node.js with a textbook example

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using `node.js` which I installed from its website according to the instructions available [here](http://nodejs.org/). I tried to execute this example from the "JavaScript - The Good Parts" textbook:

```
var myObject = {
value: 0; 
increment: function (inc) {
    this.value += (typeof inc) === 'number' ? inc : 1;
    }
};
myObject.increment( );
document.writeln(myObject.value);
myObject.increment(2);
document.writeln(myObject.value);
```

However, when I call `node test.js` (the name of the file this is in), I get the following error:

```
 value: 0;
        ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:902:3
```

This is the exact example given, which is why I'm confused as to why this isn't working. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object literals key-value pairs are separated using commas, not semicolons. Instead of this:

```
var myObject = {
    value: 0; 
    increment: function (inc) {
        this.value += (typeof inc) === 'number' ? inc : 1;
    }
};
```

Use this:

```
var myObject = {
    value: 0, 
    increment: function (inc) {
        this.value += (typeof inc) === 'number' ? inc : 1;
    }
};
```